# make image flow like Stackexchange's sites

Tags: html, css

I try to make a image waterfall like [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites), with images have different size. I try to follow the css from that but can't find the point how to have a layout like that, [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXjLwq) here. It seems items have `left: 0, top:0` under `position: absolute`, but I can't make it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's it ! You need to use `float` in CSS like that !

```
.item {
  float:left;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/Microsmsm/pen/BKarbW?editors=1100)**

> The [float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) property specifies whether or not an element should float.

Comment: Please check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyWGBM), not work as expected.